# Tracks on video tag always show “Unsafe attempt to load URL from a frame with URL

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, video

Got some strange issue with -Tag in a video html5 tag. Ionic 5 App with Angular.

The template/component code is like that:

```
<video >
<track label="Deutsch" kind="subtitles" srclang="de" [src]="this.ut_url">
</video>
```

And I tried all the Angular DOM-Functions,… but always got the same error.

```
Unsafe attempt to load URL https://www.blablbalbla.de/blbalblbalba.xml from frame with URL http://localhost/tabs/tab1. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Any ideas how I can fix that? I need to show subtitles in a video if they are available. I already now that video and track-file should be in the same path/folder to fix that, but in my configuration that is not possible.

```
public sanitizeURL(url) {
    console.log('CAll OF SANITIZE URL');
    // return this.DOMSANI.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(url); // NO!
    // return this.DOMSANI.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url); // NOT!
    // return this.DOMSANI.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url); // NO WAY
   // return this.DOMSANI.bypassSecurityTrustScript(url); // Still no way. omg
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Had to add this attribute to the video-tag:

```
crossorigin="anonymous"
```

As described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track

> src Address of the track (.vtt file). Must be a valid URL. This
> attribute must be specified and its URL value must have the same
> origin as the document — unless the  or  parent element
> of the track element has a crossorigin attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

Add aditional check to make sure the URL is safe to use.

```
public sanitizeURL(url) {
   const URL = this.DOMSANI.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL,url);
   return this.DOMSANI.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL); // Still no way. omg
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now it is showing

"ERROR Error: Required a safe URL, got a Script (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)"

which is kind of strange, because in fact he got a link to an xml-file. No Script at all.

Comment: sorry my mistake use bypassSecurityTrustUrl instead of bypassSecurityTrustScript

Comment: Thanks but I got the same error after that. I did try to use webvtt instead of xml, but it still not working. 

So far I only tried a php-script that returns an webvtt. I will test it with a direct link to the vtt file. 

But it is kind of weird for sure, because I cannot find any source that tells me what kind of byPassSecurity should be used for <track>. In my opinion it is a ResourceUrl. But I guess I am totally wrong

Comment: short update, same issue with direkt link to the .vtt-file. So it has nothing to do with the url and so on. Just want to make sure.